Не принимаются стили primevue. Primevue styles are not accepted
Не принимаются стили primevue, они работали и вдруг перестали, почему незнаю. Очищал кэш браузера, проекта, результата нет. Проект на nuxt, primevue https://v4.primevue.org/nuxt. Например в браузере brave или на некоторых версия chrome работает отлично. А в других, например: opera, edge, последняя версия chrome не работает. https://atom.com.tm




